# How to change where the horizontal axis crosses the vertical axis in geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's how I want it to look (made in Excel):
[image: excel example]

And here's the template code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- c(0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8)
qplot(x=1:6, y=data, geom="bar", stat="identity")
```

Edited after commenter suggested I need more words in my question:

My code above draws the x-axis at y=0 so that all the bars go up from the axis.
I want the x-axis to be at y=0.5 and I want bars with values < 0.5 to go *down*, while bars with values > 0.5 to go *up*. Like in the Excel plot I have placed above.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: qplot(x=1:6, y=data - 0.5, geom="bar", stat="identity") + scale_x_reverse(). ggplot tries to save the world from the most extreme scaling abuses. I don't think you can do what you really want to do without showing it on the axis.

Comment: Please see the response by @AriB.Friedman in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11398481/1492421)

Comment: I've edited my question per @RicardoSaporta's comment

Comment: @IdoTamir - your answer is not enough, I want to re-label the y-ticks so that it will go from 0 to 1, not from -0.5 to 0.5. Thanks though!

Comment: Its not an answer, its a comment. Your values are positive. Why do you lie to the reader that they are negative? Rescale your values and then you don't lie.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your comment. I'm not lying. The baseline result is 0.5 and I want to show which categories give a result of < 0.5 and which give a result of > 0.5. A horizontal line is nice but it is more clear when some bars go up and some go down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little fiddly, but possible:

```
qplot(x=factor(1:6,levels=6:1), y=data-0.5, geom="bar", stat="identity") + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-0.5,0.5,0.1),labels=seq(0,1,0.1),limits=c(-0.5,0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's the [final code](https://gist.github.com/yoavram/5606906) and the [final plot](http://i.imgur.com/S6l1XNK.png).